# Múltiplos construtores do Repositório utilizando injeção de dependência Unity Application Block C#

Tags: c#, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho um projeto que utiliza a injeção de dependência Unity Application Block.

Tem a classe do repositório:

```
public class RepositorioDeLaudoMedico: RepositorioGenericoEntityFramework<LaudoMedico, int>,
        IRepositorioDeLaudoMedico
{

    public IDbConnection Conexao;
    public RepositorioDeLaudoMedico(DbContext contexto) : base(contexto){} //construtor 1
    public RepositorioDeLaudoMedico(IDbConnection conexao) //construtor 2
    {
        this.Conexao = conexao;
    }
}
```

E na classe de injeção de dependência está assim:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepositorioDeLaudoMedico, RepositorioDeLaudoMedico>(
        new InjectionConstructor(
             new ResolvedParameter(typeof(DbContext), "ContextoLocal")
        )
);
```

Como eu faço pra incluir o segundo construtor? Eu não posso mexer no primeiro porque ele vem de uma dll...

Comment: Você pretende remover esse e inserir o outro? Qual o objetivo da troca?

Comment: eu sei que na injeção de dependência o ideal é usar só 1 construtor...

Comment: porque eu preciso criar outro acesso ao banco utilizando o dapper

Comment: Ok, se você tem esse principio constatado, imagine você que duas configurações para o mesmo registro não vai funcionar, se entende isso? Se precisa utilizar `dapper` o `contexto` dá para você também a classe que é responsável em acessar os métodos do dapper, ou seja, não precisa ser duas configurações, porque já nem funciona, somente uma e acessar os metodos de extensão que o Dapper te disponibiliza no namespace que tem que ser configurado.

Comment: EF Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935752/entity-framework-core-how-to-get-the-connection-from-the-dbcontext

Comment: Entity Frameword <=6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286071/entity-framework-getting-an-sql-connection

Comment: Essas duas formas lhe proponhe e resgatar `IDbConnection`! entende?

Comment: @RafaelaMarraschi esta era uma recomendação antiga. hoje em dia o stack de injeção escolhe o construtor com o maior número de injeções que consegue resolver.

Comment: gente, obrigada, consegui resolver, realmente com essa variável eu consegui pegar a conexão.

Answer (score 0):

sim, consegui pegar a conexão assim:

```
DbContext contexto;  IDbConnection Conexao =((IDbConnection)this.Contexto.Database.Connection);
```